# Getting HttpRequest context in self-hosted WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

How can I access the query string from a self hosted MVC WebAPI?

Call to the following failed with NRE, because Current is empty (aka. null)

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request["myQuery"]
```

I need access to the current context outside of the controller, since I want to control my object instantiation via. DI. eg.

```
        container
            .RegisterType<MyObject>(
                new InjectionFactory(
                    uc =>
                        new MyObject(
                            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request["myParam"]) //This failed.
                    ));
```

Call to `container.Resolve<MyObject>()` from inside the ControllerApi code failed, because of the above NRE.

Comment: What are you attempting to do? Use DI for HttpContext?

Comment: The other way around, use HttpContext in the DI

Comment: You'll have to use HttpContextBase in such a scenario and not the HttpContext directly.

Comment: How? I need a thread static reference as to what request the current thread is running on.

Comment: I posted the code sample as an answer. I'll improve it where needed. I feel it doesn't get to the root of your problem yet, which is why your HttpContext is null.

Comment: I deleted the answer as it isn't helping. This SO answer has the answer :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11347807/httpselfhostserver-and-httpcontext-current

Answer (score 12):

You shouldn't really use `System.Web.HttpContext.Current` in Web API. It is only valid when using Web Host and is really only there for legacy reasons.  Context information is tucked away in the `HttpRequestMessage.Properties` collection.

One of the ways that Web API improves testability is by removing its dependence on static properties.

There are ways to deal with resolving of instances and passing parameters. See this question [Unity Application Block, How pass a parameter to Injection Factory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343492/unity-application-block-how-pass-a-parameter-to-injection-factory)

Answer (score 6):

HttpContext.Current isn't available in self hosted projects

see: [HttpSelfHostServer and HttpContext.Current](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11347807/httpselfhostserver-and-httpcontext-current)

Comment: Frazell, thanks, but who's going to SetContext? I want this to be done automatically, and I hate to have to wire this up myself via filters/ webapi extension.