# JavaScript/jQuery + HTML5 file upload[.zip/.txt] And Send this file as jSON Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json, html

The question is rather simple if you have [Any server side scripting](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/server-side-script.html) techniques, but in the case of handling[viz. sending] the file as-is to the jSON function.

The scenario is :

1. I have a fileupload control

   `<input type="file" id="fileselect" name="fileselect[]" multiple="multiple" />`
2. with the help of javascript or jQuery, I need to take the uploaded file of this control on "upload" button click.
   I need to POST this file to the jSON.
3. Why need to post it as-is is because the file can be .zip or .text [Image file wont be used], I have functions in my Controllers that will work on that file[like Extract/Save/Process, etc]

Any good way that works on all browsers to do this ?

Also saving the file to the local disk using javascript is a good solution in this scenario rather than passing it to jSON ? Please comment on that also.

Answer (score 0):

With PHP it can be be done. $_FILES["fileselect"] can hold on to file arrtibutes , on upload its stored in a temp location , which can be changed by move_upload_file($source,$destination)

Comment: I am using asp.net, so using php will not be logically correct, i guess. But if I have to, how can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

For sending the request to the server side without server scripts see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22125382/746754). You can upload the file to the server using `XMLHttpRequest`. The answer is specifically about how to show a progress bar, but it also shows how to upload the files.

For the option of saving files locally using javascript, see [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/#toc-introduction) (file system API) and [here](http://www.noupe.com/webdev/html5-filesystem-api-create-files-store-locally-using-javascript-webkit.html) (localstorage). Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19017498/746754) which describes the `FileReader` and `File API`. Note that you will need to use some relatively recent features, you can refer to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=sessionstorage) to see if your targeted browsers are supported.

**Update**

As per the comments you asked how to do this with Web-API Controller. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21498397/746754). Basically, you check and loop through each file in `HttpRequest.Files` in the controller.

You can't use HttpRequest in self-hosted web API, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14350128/746754), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11496133/746754) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19884776/746754) for alternatives.

Comment: Thanks for the Reply. I am trying one of your solution of using XMLHttpRequest. I didn't mention above. I am not using **MVC Controller**. I am using **Web-API Controller**. 
I an unable to access the HttpPostedFileBase userFile there.
is there any way to pass the Parameter in this statement ?
 xhr.open("post", url, true);

Comment: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>  
<script type="text/javascript">  
 $(function () {  
  $('#Upload').click(function () {  
   var formData = new FormData();  
   var opmlFile = $('#me')[0];  
   formData.append("opmlFile", opmlFile.files[0]);  
   var baseUrl = "http://localhost:8086/api/Values/";  
   $.ajax({  
    url: baseUrl+ 'Post',  
    type: 'POST',  
    data: formData,  
    cache: false,  
    contentType: false,  
    processData: false  
   });  
  });  
 });  
</script>

Comment: ^ somehow i was not able to add linebreak in above comment. sorry for that. I was trying your solution. But it was throwing error of Nullreference in my web-Api while getting **Current** of **HttpContext** in **HttpContext.Current.Request** !! Why ?

Comment: @user3555860 - see the last line that I have just added.

Comment: what is the feasible workaround to this problem then ? How can i do this?

Comment: @user3555860 - see here: http://www.lybecker.com/blog/2013/06/26/accessing-http-request-from-asp-net-web-api/

Comment: Finally, I have to forcefully do this by Server side coding.